# PLSQL stored procedure returns no values in Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

I have a working plsql oracle stored procedure (i have tested it in plsql and it return the correct value(s)):

```
  PROCEDURE FetchCode(code OUT NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
      SELECT MYSEQ.NEXTVAL INTO code FROM DUAL;    
  END FetchCode;
```

and a visual studio solution using entity framework.

The csdl file contains

```
      <FunctionImport Name="FETCHCODE" ReturnType="Collection(Decimal)">
      <Parameter Name="CODE" Mode="Out" Type="Decimal" />
      </FunctionImport>
```

I have been successful in pulling the above function in to entity but when i try the "Get Column Information" button, I receive the "The selected stored procedure returns no columns." message.

Under edit function import I can see that it:

Returns a Collection of
Scalars: Decimal

The data type is set to "Number" and the direction is "Output".

Can anyone help explain why a sp like this would work on plsql but not in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION FetchCode IS
RETURN NUMBER
DECLARE
  code   NUMBER(10);
  BEGIN
      SELECT MYSEQ.NEXTVAL INTO code FROM DUAL;    
      RETURN code;
  END FetchCode;
```

Usually a function in Oracle is capable of returning values unlike Procedures where the output is accessed via the `OUT or IN OUT` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FetchCode
  (
     results_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  BEGIN
      OPEN results_ FOR 
      SELECT MYSEQ.NEXTVAL As Code FROM DUAL;    
  END FetchCode;
```

Comment: I tried this solution and the csdl file changed to the following:

<FunctionImport Name="ICE_UPDATEPACK_FETCHCONTACTCODE" ReturnType="Collection(Decimal)">
  <Parameter Name="P_RECORDSET" Mode="Out" Type="Binary" />
</FunctionImport>

I attempted to get column information and on execute it exits out of the 'edit function import' window entirely. It still does not seem to be returning anything on the edmx/vs side unfortunately.